# how to get optimal performance from Centrino Advanced-N 6205 wifi card

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

I've just had my home internet upgraded to 50Mb/s down, but I can only get about 25 Mb/s down on my laptop over wifi.  My phone gets about 45 Mb/s down over the same wifi and I get the full 50 Mb/s down when connected via Ethernet cable to the router, so I'm fairly sure the problem is on my laptop.

lspci says:

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)

This makes me think that for some reason iwlwifi isn't driving the card as hard as it can go:

mwhudson@narsil:~$ iwlist wlan0 rate
wlan0     unknown bit-rate information.
          Current Bit Rate:54 Mb/s

(The card can do 300Mb/s according to Intel's pages, as can my router).  I see similar performance on the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands (my phone only does 2.4Ghz).

I'm running up to date Ubuntu Saucy.

Answer (score 0):

Well so it turns out 802.11n was disabled for some reason:

```
mwhudson@narsil:~$ sudo grep 11n -r /etc
/etc/modprobe.d/intel_11n_disable.conf:options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Moving that file out of the way got me the performance I expected.